# LibreOffice Basic Ignoring “some” of my Type...End Type Definition

Tags: struct, libreoffice-basic

I'm using LibreOffice Version: 4.4.3.2 Build ID: 40m0(Build:2) Locale: en_AU

I have a Basic Module

At the top of this module before any sub or functions I have

```
Type InitHeadings
    MySort_By As Integer
    MyCharacter As Integer
    MyInitiative As Integer
    MyRolled As Integer
    MyTotal As Integer
End Type

...

Global InitiativeColumn As New InitHeadings
```

But when I run a sub, set a breakpoint and 'watch' the InitiativeColumn Object only the first two fields are shown.

[image]

The rest of my code relevant to this *struct* as the documentation calls them is below. I don't reference it anywhere else. Can anyone tell me why the first two would work but not the rest? I have two other *structs* in this code and both also ignore the last three fields. Is this a Bug?

```
Sub Main
'Initialise Doc and Sheet Objects

Dim Doc As Object

Doc = ThisComponent
StatsSheet = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Stats")
InitiativeSheet = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Initiative")
CombatSheet = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Combat")


'LOAD HEADING NAMES
'Initiative Sheet
    For Column = 0 to 25 'Columns A to Z
        MyHeadingName = InitiativeSheet.getCellByPosition(Column,0).String
        Select Case MyHeadingName
        Case "Sort By"
            InitiativeColumn.MySort_By = Column
        Case "Character"
            InitiativeColumn.MyCharacter = Column
        Case "Initiative"
            InitiativeColumn.MyInitiative = Column
        Case "Rolled"
            InitiativeColumn.MyRolled = Column
        Case "Total"
            InitiativeColumn.MyTotal = Column
        End Select
    Next Column

End Sub


Sub MyInitiativeButton

'Iterate over a range of cells:
For Row = 1 To 25 'Rows 2 to 26
    'Column 3 is column D the "Rolled" column
    InitiativeSheet.getCellByPosition(InitiativeColumn.MyRolled,Row).VALUE = Roledice(1,20,0)
Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea WHY so the question still stands but I did find a work around: If I add three additional fields `Sacrifice1 As Integer`, `Sacrifice2 As Integer`, `Sacrifice3 As Integer` to each struct this took care of the deleting the last three problem. However, `InitiativeColumn` was still not global despite the `Global InitiativeColumn As New InitHeadings` declaration. I found that if I declared a separate global variable `Global GlobalInitiativeColumn` and assigned `InitiativeColumn` to it: `GlobalInitiativeColumn = InitiativeColumn` Then GlobalInitiativeColumn WAS Global and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug, and seems to have been reported [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70494&redirected_from=fdo).  The problem did not occur when I tested it in a newer version (LO 5.1.0.3).

This is only an issue for the debugger window.  The values are still there:

```vb
Sub TestStructs
    InitiativeColumn.MySort_By = 5
    InitiativeColumn.MyCharacter = 5
    InitiativeColumn.MyTotal = 5
    InitiativeColumn.DoesntExist = 5
End Sub
```

This code works fine until the line `InitiativeColumn.DoesntExist = 5`, whereupon it crashes.

Now the `Global` problem that you mentioned in the comments is really a problem.  Considering the standard programming advice that [global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), I think it's wise to consider alternatives.

Instead of a subroutine, could you perhaps use a [Function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Procedures_and_Functions) that returns `InitiativeColumn`?  If not, then assigning the variable as you suggested seems a viable workaround.  Personally for LO macros I prefer Python or Java since they have classes.

Comment: An example of initializing a global variable using structs is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405189/5100564.