# How to pass arguments to an event listener in LibreOffice Basic?

Tags: events, scope, lifetime, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am writing a macro to automate tasks on a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc.
One of those tasks is simply to add the numbers contained in a given cell range and write the total in the appropriate cell when one of these cells is edited. (The cells actually contain text: the names of different services. The program then fetches the number of hours associated with each service's name to add them all up.)

Editing such a cell triggers the `Modify_modified(oEv)` event listener.
The listener then calls the subroutine `UpdateTotalHoursOfAgent(calendarSize, allServices, agentTopleftCell)` which performs the task described above.

The problem is that arguments `calendarSize` and `allServices`, which are defined in other places in the code, are out of scope in the event listener.

I do not know how to pass those arguments to the listener.
I tried using global variables instead even though it is frowned upon, but I suspect that they reach the end of their lifetime when the main program's execution is complete, and are not available anymore when a cell is edited afterwards.

How can I pass arguments `calendarSize` and `allServices` to the `UpdateTotalHoursOfAgent` subroutine when `Modify_modified(oEv)` is triggered?

Here's part of the code used to create the event listener (found on a forum):

```basic
Private oListener, cellRange as Object

Sub AddListener
    Dim sheet, cell as Object

    sheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByIndex(0)  'get leftmost sheet
    cellRange = sheet.getCellrangeByName("E4:J5")

    
    oListener = createUnoListener("Modify_","com.sun.star.util.XModifyListener")  'create a listener
    cellRange.addModifyListener(oListener)  'register the listener
End Sub

Sub Modify_modified(oEv)

' *Compute agentTopleftCell*

REM How to obtain calendarSize and allServices from here?
    UpdateTotalHoursOfAgent(calendarSize, allServices, agentTopleftCell)
End Sub

Sub Main
' *...code...*
    Dim allServices As allServicesStruct
    Dim calendarSize As calendarStruct

    AddListener

' *...code...*
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! *"tasks is simply to add the numbers contained in a given cell range and write the total in the appropriate cell when one of these cells is edited"* - why not formula like as `=SUM(E4:J5)` in target cell?

Comment: @JohnSUN Thank you! I should have mentioned that the cells actually contain text: the user types in the names of different services, and the program automatically fetches the number of hours associated with each service's name to add them all up.

Comment: Yes, `SUM()` won't work in this case. However, you can easily convert `UpdateTotalHoursOfAgent(calendarSize, allServices, agentTopleftCell)` into a user defined function and write something like `=UPDATETOTALHOURSOFAGENT(Sizes.$B$4:$C$24, Dictionary.$B$8:$C$31, E4:J5)` into the target cell. If you do not turn off Auto-recalculation, then the function will be calculated for any change in the cells in the specified ranges - is this exactly the result that you are trying to achieve using the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using global variables...

Probably you did not do it correctly. Here is how to set a global variable.

```vb
Private oListener, cellRange as Object
Global AllServices

Type allServicesStruct
    svc As String
End Type

Sub AddListener
    Dim sheet, cell as Object
    sheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByIndex(0)  'get first sheet
    cellRange = sheet.getCellrangeByName("E4:J5")
    oListener = createUnoListener("Modify_","com.sun.star.util.XModifyListener")
    cellRange.addModifyListener(oListener)
End Sub

Sub Modify_modified(oEv)
    MsgBox AllServices.svc
End Sub

Sub Main
    Dim allServicesLocal As allServicesStruct
    allServicesLocal.svc = "example"
    AllServices = allServicesLocal
    
    AddListener
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: example message box]

This was adapted from my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405189/5100564